# Seeking commercial Geocoding API

Tags: geocoding, software-recommendations

We are looking for a free or paid version of a Geocoding API that will allow us to use it for commercial purposes that is as good as google. Google's api starts at $10,000 a year which is too much. We expect to do 1000-5000 geocodes per month.

I have tried Cloudmade, but have had problems geocoding some addresses that google can do.

Does anyone have any recommendations based on experience?

Here is how I am using the Cloudmade API:

http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/API_KEY/api/geo.location.search.2?format=json&source=OSM&enc=UTF-8&limit=10&locale=en&q=%5Bcountry%3DUnited%20States%5D%5Bstate%3DNY%5D%5Bzip%3DZIP%5D%5Bcity%3DCITY%5DAddressRemoved

Comment: Are you able to edit your Question to include a few of the addresses that Cloudmade had problems with, and what those specific problems were?  That way anyone proposing an alternative to Google will be able to test them before Answer-ing.

Comment: See [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62374/geocoding-api-comparison) for a link to a document comparing 11 different geocoding services. Note: This might have been compiled *before* SmartyStreets improved their geocoding accuracy.

Comment: I have posted how I am using the API with address removed for privacy

Answer (score 9):

We did a comparison of geocoding vendors recently, and came up with this:

- [Yahoo Boss Geo Services](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/) 0-10,000 queries/day for $0-$60/day
- [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com/pricing) 10,000 queries/month for $80
- [EPI Internet Direct (Bing Maps Reseller)](http://www.epidirect.com/ms/mappoint/SSum.htm) - 15000 queries/quarter for $200
- [MapQuest Enterpise](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/terms-overview) 500,000 queries/year for $5000
- [geocod.io](http://geocod.io/pricing/)  2500 geocodes/day (free), $0.001/query after that.

Geocod.io is the cheapest, but their geocoder is based on Tiger data, and is probably incorrect in many places.  The others are comparable to the Google API in terms of accuracy, but may have various restrictions in their Terms Of Use or levels of customer service that may make them unsuitable for your use.  As always, you get what you pay for.

Update, 2016: Geocodio has added a significant number of additional datasets and reduced their pricing to $.0005 per lookup after the initial 2,500 free per day. They have also created a tool so you can compare their accuracy and pricing to other prodivers: http://geocod.io/compare/

Comment: Do you have any results on accuracy?

Comment: Only for Yahoo and EPI Internet Direct.  Those two were similar to Google.  We needed parcel-level accuracy and were able to get it in 99% of cases from those two vendors.

Answer (score 4):

[locationiq.com](http://locationiq.com) - 10k geocodes/ day for free. LocationIQ is based on data from OpenStreetMap, OpenAddresses, WhosonFirst, Polylines, TIGER & Geonames.

Disclaimer: I work for Unwired Labs, which owns locationiq.org

Answer (score 2):

This question is over 4 years old and a lot has changed since. [Geocode.xyz](https://geocode.xyz)
is a two year old startup that does both address cleanup/standardization, geoparsing and geocoding. Provides elevation too.

Comment: As one data point, on the front page of the geocode.xyz website, I searched for the address "20459 Pin Oak Road, new carey, tx". It brought me to some crazy location in Nova Scotia.

Comment: http://geocoder.ca/20459+Pin+Oak+Rd,+New+Caney,+TX works (use geocoder.ca for North America) and http://geocode.xyz/20459+Pin+Oak+Rd,+New+Caney,+TX works too, but is less accurate.

Comment: Ervin, I see that your links work, but when I go to http://geocode.xyz/ and type "20459 Pin Oak Road, new carey, tx" into the box and click the Next button, I'm brought to Nova Scotia. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you set the region parameter as Canada? When the software can not make a match, it tries to guess the country. Also "new carey" is the wrong city name, it should be "New Caney". When I enter that text in the search box of geocode.xyz, I get: "Not Found.
Suggestion: 20459 PIN OAK ROAD NEW CANEY TX"

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".

Answer (score 1):

I work for TomTom. Have you checked our [TomTom Maps APIs](https://developer.tomtom.com)?

The Search API provides for Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding and the free tier account is probably enough for your needs.

Take a look at our [tutorials](https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-web/functional-examples#geocode). The API KEY registration is free (no credit card needed)

More information in the [Search API](https://developer.tomtom.com/products/search-api) documentation.